# Android Error On Asynchronous Click

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This is my Method

```
private TextView monthTotal;
    private TextView yearTotal;
    private ExpenseDal expenseDal;

    private EditText amountText;
    private EditText descText;
    private EditText categoryText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        expenseDal = new ExpenseDal(this);
        amountText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountText);
        descText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descText);
        categoryText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.categoryText);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_expense_list);
        monthTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.monthTotal);
        yearTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yearTotal);
        monthTotal.setText(expenseDal.getCurrentMonthTotal());
        yearTotal.setText(expenseDal.getCurrentYearTotal());

        //Event For Save Button
        Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (amountText.getText().length() != 0) {
                    AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveExpenseTask = new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
                            saveExpense();
                            return null;
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    };

                    saveExpenseTask.execute((Object[]) null);
                }

                else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            ExpenseList.this);
                    alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle);
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null);
                    alert.show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void saveExpense() { }
```

My trace below

```
12-17 04:53:53.003: D/AndroidRuntime(2484): Shutting down VM
12-17 04:53:53.003: W/dalvikvm(2484): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at com.technowizsol.easyexpensemanager.ExpenseList$1.onClick(ExpenseList.java:45)
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-17 04:53:53.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2484):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error is on the line where i check the amount is null or not. Any ideas why im getting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_expense_list);
```

move it so it is directly below

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

The way you have it set up now, is you're trying to find some Views in the layout before actually setting the layout. And so, `findViewById()` isn't finding anything for those Views (nothing exists yet), and so, it returns **null**.

Also, you're not checking if `amountText` is null, you're checking to see if its text length is 0 - two separate things. Since `amountText` is actually not holding a reference to anything, you get a NPE.

Comment: i found out the issue just after i posted this. Now theres another issue. After the insert operation the application comes out. Any ideas why? Is it because the insert operation is asynchronous?

Comment: Application comes out? Mind elaborating? Also, you don't have much of an implementation in your Task, it calls an empty method at the moment.

Comment: I am testing it in emulator. What happens is after i click on save button. The app closes and comes back to the home screen. The record is inserted successfully, there is no errors or warnings in logs, but the app just closes and comes out to the home screen

Comment: Because you call `finish()`. That actually makes the Activity finish!